# Whay the plot colors are the same in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot poison distribution for different lambda in a plot
my code is as follow

```
    lamda = [1,4,5,10]
pres = np.zeros((len(lamda),200))
for i in range(len(lamda)):
    l = lamda[i]
    t = np.arange(0, 20, 0.1)
    d = np.exp(-l)*np.power(l, t)/factorial(t)
    print (len(d))
    for j in range (len(d)):
        pres[i][j] = d[j]

revresepres = np.zeros((len(d),len(lamda)))
for i in range (len(d)):
    for j in range (len(lamda)):
          revresepres[i][j] = pres [j][i]
plt.plot(revresepres,'bs')

plt.legend(lamda)

plt.show()
```

I know by default the colour of lines are different. but the result of this code is as follow [![enter image description here][1]][1]

can you please guide me, why all the colours are the same. I appreciate your help in advance
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFsim.png

Comment: d is not specified in your code, it throws an error. Kindly upload the complete code.

Comment: This is my whole code, d is what is used in line 6. I fixed it in my code and edited it here by the resulting does not change

Comment: By default all the colors will be blue:

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can change the colour?

Comment: you could try using matplotlib's colormap to add color to the graph.

Comment: @yaldasana I have posted a code as an example in answer. It might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how you can change color in different types of graphs-

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def f(t):
    return np.exp(-t) * np.cos(2 * np.pi * t)


t1 = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.1)
t2 = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.02)

plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(t1, f(t1), t2, f(t2), "o-")

plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(t2, np.cos(2 * np.pi * t2), "o-") 

plt.show()
```

Comment: thank you. but I want to show the dots like the sample, not a continuous line. do you have any idea?

Comment: I have edited it kindly check for the dots like sample.

Comment: you can check it out here-- https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html